# Meaning of abbreviation ск.аз

Tags: грамматика

I found this in an online dictionary under горячий as an example:

> Горячо (в значение ск.аз.) рукам

Does anyone have any idea of what it stands for?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is a misprint, `сказ.`(abbreviation for the `сказуемое`) is more probable.

Comment: I see. Thank you. And what does горячо рукам actually mean?

Comment: I'm not good enough in English, sorry, but I'll try: `hands feel hot` or `I feel hot in hands`.

Comment: In that case, there's another misprint there: the proper spelling would be "в значении сказ."

Comment: @AndreyT I agree.

Answer (score 1):

[Google search](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%BE%20(%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA.%D0%B0%D0%B7.)%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&rlz=&gfe_rd=cr&ei=CVwgVMqlN4PMwwPV3oDACA&gws_rd=ssl#rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&q=%22(%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA.%D0%B0%D0%B7.)%22) for `(в значение ск.аз.)` yelds 3 results, one of them being here, ther other two being copies of a dictionary article. On the other hand, [search](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%BE%20(%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA.%D0%B0%D0%B7.)%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&rlz=&gfe_rd=cr&ei=CVwgVMqlN4PMwwPV3oDACA&gws_rd=ssl#rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&q=%22(%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7.)%22) for `(в значение сказ.)` yealds over 800 different articles, so I'm positive the dot is just a misprint.

Comment: Thank you and what does в значении сказ. actually mean?

Comment: It means that this word is used as a predicate, in this particular case, it's an adverb "Горячо" performing a function usually performed by a verb. "Рукам горячо" means "hands burn", analogous in sentence structure to "hands hurt" - "Рукам больно". 'Он приложил руки к корпусу и сказал :"Горячо рукам"' - 'He put his hands on a hull and said "Hands burn"'. Such sentence structure is mostly used in colloquial speech. Normally,'горячо' would be an adverb and mean 'passionately' (literal translation being 'hotly'). 'Я горячо люблю тебя' - 'I love you passionately'.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but thanks for the explanation :)